# How to remove controller list from Swagger UI

Tags: java, swagger-ui

I'm using springfox-swagger-ui 2.8.0 which ships with Swagger UI 3.7.0.

I want to get rid of the controller list in front of the api documentation page, pretty useless for me (every tab is empty).

I've already tried to annotate the controller class with @ApiIgnore, but of course this removes the rest api documentation as well, which I need.

Basically, I want to remove this:

[image: Controller list to remove/hide]

while keeping this:

[image: REST api docs to keep]

I digged through online docs, GitHub issues, StackOverflow questions, Google... nothing. Am I the only with this request?

Comment: This sould be good feature request on springfox team

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031852/4978689), I tried and it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the attribute description to `@Api`:

For example:

```
@Api(value = "Test API Controller", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, tags = {"test-api-controller"}, description = "Testing API")
```

Comment: I already had the description attribute (and it's marked as deprecated). Removing it changes nothing :-(

Comment: YES! Your hint led me to the right solution: adding @Api(tags = {"MagazzinoPF"}) to the implementation class. This someway "merges" the empty documentation line to the actual documentation below. If you modify your answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @think01 Solved my problem too. Do you think there is a way to add this when generating swagger code itself?

Comment: @NuttLoose uhm, good idea, unfortunately I don't know how to achieve that. I'll look about it, if you find the way, please share it here ;-)

Comment: @think01 Will do.

Comment: it hides both in 2.9.2

Comment: Are there any options to hide this on the generated swagger code?

Comment: its not clear from the ans, using the same tag name on some controllers will merge all apis under them to a single grouping ```@Api(tags = {"GroupingName"}```

Comment: It hides also in 3.0.0. Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 33):

Try this attribute on the controller

`[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`

Comment: If you're using ASPCore and need to assure the route is not accessible, add `app.Map("/api/values", delegate { });` to method `Configure` in `Startup.cs`

Comment: Don't know if this attribute works in Java, but in ASP.Net Core 2.2 it works nice. The controller is still accessible via URL, but it's hidden from the swagger output.

Comment: Is there a way to add this dynamically at run-time?

Answer (score 3):

on springfox v3.0 tried almost every annotations and finally
@ApiIgnore annotation works.
Don't know why @Api(hidden=true) doesn't work.

```
import springfox.documentation.annotations.ApiIgnore;
@ApiIgnore
@Responsebody
public Object ...{}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the OpenAPI `@ApiIgnore` and `@Api` annotations may not work.

Use `@Hidden` annotation on the controller you want swagger-ui to ignore/exclude and thank me later.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I expected the `hidden` attribute will work but it doesn't. I also tried to set `description` and also doesn't work.

Another solution is to use the `tag` in the @Api can help you temporarily hide this rest-controllers list and categorize your APIs in different tags.

Answer (score 0):

Set the attribute at controller level
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]

To hide the property just use
[JsonIgnore]
i.e., namespace system.text.json.serialization

Answer (score -2):

springfox api version 2.9.2

works with the below example by adding on a controller class

@Api(value = "Test API Controller", tags = {"test-api-controller"}, description = "Testing API")

Comment: Someone already made the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50739276/5022959
Please don't answer on a closed question with the same answer as the accepted answer.