# How to hide endpoints from Swagger documentation with Springfox

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a Spring Boot project with next dependency of Springfox:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have my Interface:

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import springfox.documentation.annotations.ApiIgnore;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/cache")
@ApiIgnore
@Api(hidden = true)
public interface CacheController {

    @RequestMapping(
        value = "clear/",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE}
    )
    @ApiOperation(value = "", hidden = true)
    ResponseEntity<String> clearToken();
}
```

The annotations `@ApiIgnore` and `@Api(hidden = true)` (I've tested them separately and they don't work either.) haven't effects to hide the documentation. It only works if the annotation is over the method, but I would like hide them all since I have other endpoints I'd like to hide.

Some ideas?

EDIT:

This is my Swagger configuration:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ResponseMessageBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiKey;
import springfox.documentation.service.AuthorizationScope;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.service.ResponseMessage;
import springfox.documentation.service.SecurityReference;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.SecurityContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    public static String API_KEY_NAME;

    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocumentation() {
        List<ResponseMessage> errorList = this.defineResponseMessages();

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()       
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.package.rest"))              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build()
          .useDefaultResponseMessages(true)
          .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, errorList)
          .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(this.apiKey()))
          .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(this.securityContext()))
          .apiInfo(this.apiInfo());                                          
    }

    @Value("${server.security.apiKeyName}")
    public void setApiKeyName(final String apiKeyName) {
        SwaggerConfig.API_KEY_NAME = apiKeyName;
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("apiKey", API_KEY_NAME, "header");
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder()
            .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("apiKey", authorizationScopes));
    }

    private List<ResponseMessage> defineResponseMessages() {
        List<ResponseMessage> errorList = new ArrayList<ResponseMessage>();

        ResponseMessage responseMessage = new ResponseMessageBuilder()
            .code(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value())
            .message(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getReasonPhrase())
            .build();

        errorList.add(responseMessage);

        responseMessage = new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                .code(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value())
                .message(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase())
                .build();

        errorList.add(responseMessage);

        responseMessage = new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                .code(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value())
                .message(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getReasonPhrase())
                .build();

        errorList.add(responseMessage);

        return errorList;
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfoBuilder apiInfoBuilder = new ApiInfoBuilder();
        return apiInfoBuilder
            .title("My API")
            .description("Description")
            .version("1.0.0 Beta")
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your Swagger Docket configuration look like?

Comment: I have edited the post to add the Swagger configuration

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have added the `@ApiIgnore` annotation on an interface. It looks like, this annotation doesn't work when added on an interface. (I really don't understand why `@Api` works on an interface and `@ApiIgnore` don't. )

Add the annotation directly to your controller class. This should solve your problem.

The `hidden` property on the `@Api` annotation doesn't work currently. (See [this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2437) GitHub issue.)

---

For Springdoc see: [How to hide endpoints from OpenAPI documentation with Springdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102261)

Answer (score 15):

For *OpenAPI3* and *SpringBoot*:
I used @Hidden annotation on a method of a controller.
It seems to work both at method level and controller level.

@Hidden annotation was imported from using:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations;
```

Answer (score 9):

One more way is to use `@ApiOperation(hidden = true)`
This can be used at controller/handler level method.
E.g.

```
@RestController
public HomeController{
@ApiOperation(value = "<Your Message>", hidden = true)
    public String getMessage(@RequestParam(value = "msg") final String msg){
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: I resolved hiddon the operation too. By my docs was in a interface. A recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

The scenario where we want to hide only a particular method(s) from the class. For swagger.v3 there is an annotation with name `Hidden` in `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.0.10 jar`. Methods to be hidden can be annotated with `Hidden` annotation as shown below. The below method shows the method with `DELETE` operation which needs to be hidden from the swagger documentation.

```
@DELETE
@Hidden
public void deleteList(int id) {
//code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  And it is found here `import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Hidden;`

Answer (score 4):

Another different great way is to define the visible paths on the SpringFox Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(Predicates.or(PathSelectors.ant("/rtm/**"), PathSelectors.ant("/appview/**")))
                .build().apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
    }
}
```

This way you can define the visible paths centraly and avoid puting swagger annotations on many controllers.

Answer (score -8):

Another option is to just remove the @Api completely, and your controller and its methods shouldn't be picked up by swagger.