# Enforce which Controllers show on my Swagger-UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a bunch of controllers in my spring boot controller package. I don't want all to show up on my Swagger-UI interface.

Any idea of how I can instruct Swagger-UI to show all but 1 ????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide endpoints from Swagger documentation in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010362/how-to-hide-endpoints-from-swagger-documentation-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Yes !!!!!
Thanks a bunch, I appreciate