# Swagger Hide Certain Endpoints With Same Path or Same Http Method

Tags: java, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have the following endpoints, I want to expose the first 2 endpoints only:

```
POST /person // show in Swagger
GET  /person // Do Not show in Swagger

GET  /order // show in Swagger
```

I have my Swagger configured as:

```
@Bean
public Docket swaggerApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("externalUser")
            .select()              
            .paths(Predicates.or(
                    PathSelectors.ant("/person"),
                    PathSelectors.ant("/order")))
            .apis(Predicates.or(
       RequestHandlerSelectors.withMethodAnnotation(PostMapping.class),   
       RequestHandlerSelectors.withMethodAnnotation(GetMapping.class)))
            .build();
```

But the issue is that the second endpoint (`GET /person`) also appears in the Swagger openApi because it matches the path also the http method configured for Swagger. How do I change my configure so that the second endpoint will not appear in Swagger? I cannot use `@ApiIgnore` or `hidden=true` on `@ApiOperation` because for internal users, we want to let them see all endpoints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide endpoints from Swagger documentation with Springfox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010362/how-to-hide-endpoints-from-swagger-documentation-with-springfox)

Comment: @JoostPapendorp I can't use ApiOperation because this is for external customers and for internal users, we will want to show them all endpoints.

Comment: Well, one option is to merge two Dockets. Docket does not offer that afaik, but one could facade the Docket with a class to allow for multiple Docket, checking each independently by forwarding the calls. Bit last resort messy, but I think that the library authors expected this use case to be handled by the annotations.